# why this code doesn't function

Tags: php, include

im trying to include a PHP file in my home page
the php file inside a div next another div had image but it doesn't funtion and it retruns 500 server error
this is the code

```
<div>
<?php 
if ( is_front_page() ) {
<div style="padding:0 10px 0 20px; width: 80%; float: left;"> 
include 'test.php';</div> <div style="float: left;"></div>}?>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't just put HTML in the middle of your PHP code. You need to close your PHP first.

Comment: Look at the PHP error logs.  They're telling you that this isn't valid PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
<?php 
if ( is_front_page() ) {
?>
<div style="padding:0 10px 0 20px; width: 80%; float: left;"> 
<?php include 'test.php'; ?>
</div>
<div style="float: left;"></div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

When using html within php, you should remember to close the php tags, and then open php tags again when beginning on the php again.

Comment: it doesn't include the php file

Comment: Are you sure that is_front_page() is returning true ? You can maybe try to just echo some dummy thing into the div to see if that works, if not, then is_front_page() isn't returning true. ^^

Comment: No problem, always trying to help :)